# Pandas time Slices

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv and then return a dataframe based off a time slice.

```
Date    Time    Transaction No.
7/3/2017    15:26:54    2141439
7/3/2017    15:26:44    2142226
7/3/2017    15:25:26    2132076
7/3/2017    15:24:17    2141038
7/3/2017    15:20:55    2140073
7/3/2017    15:16:28    2133436
7/3/2017    15:10:48    2134561
7/3/2017    14:40:26    2125436
7/3/2017    14:35:50    2133569
7/3/2017    14:33:18    2126370
7/3/2017    14:31:42    2132945
```

Above is what my csv looks like I am trying the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv',parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

I would want to return only values between 14:30 and 15:00. I tried adding index_col =[0] to the read_csv function but I am getting a little lost of how to return the data I am looking. My initial thought was to make my index be a datetime index and use the between function to get what I desired but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `index_col` for `DatetimeIndex` and then filter by [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv',index_col=['Date_Time'], parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
print (df)
                     Transaction No.
Date_Time                           
2017-07-03 15:26:54          2141439
2017-07-03 15:26:44          2142226
2017-07-03 15:25:26          2132076
2017-07-03 15:24:17          2141038
2017-07-03 15:20:55          2140073
2017-07-03 15:16:28          2133436
2017-07-03 15:10:48          2134561
2017-07-03 14:40:26          2125436
2017-07-03 14:35:50          2133569
2017-07-03 14:33:18          2126370
2017-07-03 14:31:42          2132945


df = df.between_time('14:30', '15:00')
print (df)
                     Transaction No.
Date_Time                           
2017-07-03 14:40:26          2125436
2017-07-03 14:35:50          2133569
2017-07-03 14:33:18          2126370
2017-07-03 14:31:42          2132945
```